# Content Porter 2013 Sp1 importing dependencies

Tags: content-porter-2013-sp1

I've exported some pages from one environment and i'm aiming to put only the pages into another environment.

The new environment contains the schemas and components needed, i'm purely wishing to import only the pages.

I configure the import to only include 'Content' (see image below)

[image]

When importing, i select only the structure groups and pages in the publication:

[image]

But I notice during the import that components and schemas are being included:

[image]

I've always used earlier versions of CP in the same way and had the results that I expected... it's been a while though, so either I'm doing something strange or there seems to be something different about Content Porter 2013 SP1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want dependencies. don't check any checkboxes in "Select Dependency" dialog.

Comment: And you can do the same when exporting (though that assumes you _really_ have all the dependencies on the target system)

Comment: I think that's probably the commonest use case for Content Porter: when you're moving new changes through DTAP, most of the time you should know exactly what you're exporting, and switch off dependencies to get a clean export.

Comment: It still doesn't look right to me. I'd expect the Components and Keywords (.tkw -- the first few items have "Schema" in the path but are not Schemas). But why *is* the Publication Metadata Schema being moved? I'd expect Schemas if @John checked `Definition`.

Comment: FWIW, the dependency filters did change in [2009](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ContentPorter_2009_SP1/JD8856JJDKS992YYR6859005KKD5543F) and [2013](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-FABB693D-49F4-4E1B-A88F-A5F25EE6D205). These changes were for new types of items and a change to how we make Default Building Blocks.